# Error when tar a compressed file

Tags: linux, compression, zip, tar, archiving

I try to install krona tools, so I downloaded its archive first as follows:

```
curl -LOk https://github.com/marbl/Krona/releases/download/v2.7/KronaTools-2.8.tar
```

then
#untar

```
tar -xvf KronaTools-2.8.tar
```

---

> tar: This does not look like a tar archive
> tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

then tried

```
tar -zxvf KronaTools-2.8.tar
```

got this

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

also

```
tar tvf KronaTools-2.8.tar
```

got this

```
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

another trial

```
file KronaTools-2.8.tar
KronaTools-2.8.tar: ASCII text, with no line terminators
mv KronaTools-2.8.tar KronaTools-2.8.tar.zip ; unzip KronaTools-2.8.tar.zip
```

I got

```
Archive:  KronaTools-2.8.tar.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of KronaTools-2.8.tar.zip or
        KronaTools-2.8.tar.zip.zip, and cannot find KronaTools-2.8.tar.zip.ZIP, period.
```

Any help please!

Comment: KronaTools-2.8.tar can be  a ~9B file, when you are using curl. .... Download KronaTools ( source ) : `wget https://github.com/marbl/Krona/archive/refs/tags/v2.8.tar.gz` ..... and you will get `v2.8.tar.gz` , **401.2 kB**. .......... https://github.com/marbl/Krona/releases

Comment: @KnudLarsen Indeed! Do you know why there's a diff between curl and wget?

Comment: Please have a look here https://github.com/marbl/Krona/releases ... and try out the different ways of downloading files : Click "KronaTools-2.8.tar" and get 781kB. Click "Source code" and get `Krona-2.8.tar.gz` 410.0kB . ..... And no, I don't know how the design of the download page is making this difference, but it has been answered recently for a similar situation.

Comment: OK. At least I learned why the Download page was empty... the Wiki points to wiki/downloads, not /marbl/Krona/releases. I'm taking off my now-irrelevant answer :-)

Comment: Thanks so much. I downloaded the file successfully using source code, then unzipped it by tar -xvzf Krona-2.8.tar.gz, then, sudo ./install.pl

Comment: Thanks so much. I downloaded the file successfully using source code, then unzipped it by tar -xvzf Krona-2.8.tar.gz